# No matching member function in Map insert

Tags: c++

I have the following two variables:

```
static vector<map<uint32_t,vector<uint64_t>>> relations;
static map<uint64_t,map<uint32_t,vector<uint64_t>>> transactions;

uint64_t key1;
uint32_t key2;
uint32_t key3;
// init keys...
```

And I am trying to copy one `vector` from `relations` into `transactions`:

```
transactions[key1][key2].push_back(relations[key2][key3]));
```

But I find this error:

```
main.cpp:175:26: error: no matching member function for call to 'push_back'
     transactions[key1][key2].push_back(relations[key2][key3]));
     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/../include/c++/v1/vector:700:36: note: candidate function not viable: no
  known conversion from 'vector<uint64_t>' to 'const value_type' (aka 'const unsigned long long') for 1st argument
_LIBCPP_INLINE_VISIBILITY void push_back(const_reference __x);
                               ^
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/../include/c++/v1/vector:702:36: note: candidate function not viable: no
  known conversion from 'vector<uint64_t>' to 'value_type' (aka 'unsigned long long') for 1st argument
_LIBCPP_INLINE_VISIBILITY void push_back(value_type&& __x);
```

Any idea of what's happening?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`relations[key2][key3]` is a `vector<uint64_t>`, and you're trying to add it to `transactions[key1][key2]` which is a `vector<uint64_t>`.

You can't add `vector<uint64_t>` to a `vector<uint64_t>`.

---

If you'd like to add the *contents* of the first `vector` to the second one, you need to use [`std::vector::insert`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/insert):

```
auto& dst = transactions[key1][key2];
const auto& src = relations[key2][key3];
dst.insert(dst.end(), src.begin(), src.end());
```